# Why my Post api run in postman but doesn't run in react-native app

Tags: android, api, react-native, laravel-5, postman

[image]
I'm trying to update 1 item to my server. It works in Post man.

[image]
But in react-native app, it does not work!

Comment: [you can check solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60307250/11167377) feel free for doubts.

Answer (score 1):

```
 const image = 
   {
        uri: image.path,//add here your local path
        type: image.mime, //add here your image type
        name: timestamp + '.' + image.mime.split('/')[1]//add here your image name
   }
```

In your body part

add like

```
 food_img:image
```